# C# Alternative to virtual static methods and static sub classes

Tags: c#, inheritance, static, virtual

Whenever I read questions RE this, or a similar topic of static inheritance, the replies are usually that this is not supported (we know that), and the reason is given as being because this is a poor design and there's probably a better way to do it. I'd love to find a better way of doing it so am open to all suggestions - here's what I am trying to do.

I have a class which has no instance data. All the methods are static. Let's call this `class BaseStatic`. I now want a new static class (well several of course but lets stick to one) which inherits from this static class and adds some new static methods, let's call this `SubStatic`.

What I want consumers to be able to write is:

```
SubStatic.MethodFromSub();
```

and also

```
SubStatic.MethodFromBase();
```

I know I could also write:

```
BaseStatic.MethodFromBase()
```

explicitly but then consumers have to know which class implements which methods. I can't do this with inheritance because I can't inherit one static class from another. So what's a better way of doing it?

Now, I know I can have these classes as instance classes, and I can define all the methods as static - that will give me the behaviour I described above but leads to other problems, namely:

1. When I do this:`SubStatic.MethodFromBase()` the `SubStatic` static constructor is not called because the method is running in the parent static class (the parent's static constructor is called)
2. If one of the static parent methods needs to call another method which the sub class can override, I need a virtual static method in the sub class. Which I know I can't have.

So poor design apparently - can anyone help me redo it? I know I can use instance inheritance and take proper use of virtual methods (I've had it working this way) but client code then always has to create an instance (or I suppose some singleton).

Comment: You can use singleton design pattern in which you create the instance and return them to user. Wouldn't that help you to solve your problem?

Comment: Yes - but then I'm still creating an instance aren't I? Also, consumers would have to write: SomeClass.Instance.SomeMethod(), right?

Comment: Yes, you have to create instances, but only once and then you can cache them by using Lazy Loading pattern. This is the only way you can have inheritance. Also, this would lead to more flexible code.

Comment: Is it necessary that just that particular class's cctor be run (the one whose qualifier is being used instead of the base)? Or is it OK if all loaded implementations' cctors are run?

Comment: I can probably work with either way...

Comment: It is not poor design. You are just trying to avoid the solution the language gives you, for a reason which is not clear to me. C# has very good support for static object members (compared to, e.g., C++ where you run into problems regularly due to unspecified order of initialization), so just use the singleton pattern.

Comment: Yes I could use singleton - clear - but if I'm doing that I may as well make it an instance class with instance methods, no, and forget singleton? I don't care if people instantiate it multiple times there is no instance data...hey I don't want it instantiated at all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could serve your purpose, though I certainly would include some exception handling and accompany its implementation with a great deal of documentation as to why and how it works.

When the static constructor for `Base` is run (once) all assemblies that are currently loaded in the app domain are catalogued, selecting the types that derive from `Base`.  Iterating over those, we run the static constructors.  It is worth noting though, that this no longer guarantees the cctor for each implementation will be run exactly once, logic would have to be added to each of them to re-make that assertion.  Moreover, types that are loaded after the cctor for `Base` has been run would not be initialized by calls to methods in `Base`

To simulate virtual methods, use the `new` keyword to hide the base method. You can call the base method by qualifying it with the declaring class's name (like in class `B` in the example)

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication6
{
    public class Base
    {
        static Base()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Base cctor");

            var thisType = typeof (Base);
            var loadedTypes = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes());
            var derivations = loadedTypes.Where(thisType.IsAssignableFrom);

            foreach(var derivation in derivations)
            {
                RuntimeHelpers.RunClassConstructor(derivation.TypeHandle);
            }
        }

        public static void Foo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Bar");
        }
    }

    public class A : Base
    {
        static A()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("A cctor");
        }
    }

    public class B : Base
    {
        static B()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("B cctor");
        }

        public new static void Foo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Bar!!");
            Base.Foo();
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("A:");
            A.Foo();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("B:");
            B.Foo();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Base:");
            Base.Foo();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Another option lies in the CRTP (or CRGP in the C# paradigm) or curiously recurring template (generic) parameter pattern

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication6
{
    public class Base<T>
        where T : Base<T>
    {
        static Base()
        {
            RuntimeHelpers.RunClassConstructor(typeof (T).TypeHandle);
        }

        public static void Foo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Bar");
        }
    }

    public class Base : Base<Base>
    {
    }

    public class A : Base<A>
    {
        static A()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("A cctor");
        }
    }

    public class B : Base<B>
    {
        static B()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("B cctor");
        }

        public new static void Foo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Bar!!");
            Base<B>.Foo();
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("A:");
            A.Foo();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("B:");
            B.Foo();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Base:");
            Base.Foo();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

In this case, when we call a static method on `A` we're really calling it on `Base<A>` which is different than `Base<B>` or `Base` so we *can* actually determine how the method was called and run the appropriate cctor.

Comment: Hmm - very clever but one issue I would see is that all static sub class constructors would be called - I might have 100 such sub classes and this would be wasteful. It's interesting that people are suggesting ways to make this work rather than tellingme why the design is bad.

Comment: @RBrowning99 this is exactly why I asked you if it was OK if all the derived classes cctors were called though ;)

Comment: I misunderstood your question - I thought you were asing whether I cared whether the parent or the sub class constuctor was called. Sorry.

Comment: @RBrowning99 added another option that deals with the potential of large derivation counts but adds a bit of complexity

Comment: That looks great - I'll have a play when I'm fresh tomorrow and might be all I need.

Comment: Works like a treat. I can now write this: public abstract partial class CustomerBLLRepository : BaseBLLRepository<CustomerLite, Customer, CustomerBLLRepository>n and my child constructors which always get called    static CustomerBLLRepository()
    {
      Mapper.CreateMap<CustomerLite, Customer>().AfterMap((bllEntity, dalEntity) =>
                                           ConvertBLLToDAL(bllEntity, dalEntity));
      Mapper.CreateMap<Customer, CustomerLite>().AfterMap((dalEntity, bllEntity) =>
                                                 ConvertDALToBLL(dalEntity, bllEntity));
    }

Comment: In your CRTP/CRGP example, what does that generic type constraint look like if `Base<T>` is actually `Base<T1, T2>`?  I'm going cross-eyed at this point so maybe I'm overlooking the obvious.

Comment: @JMD So if you need an additional type parameter it's a bit easier to think of it as `Base<TSelf, T0, T1, ...>`, self always being the first parameter & everything else after. So, it'd be `class Base<TSelf, TSomethingElse> where TSelf : Base<TSelf, TSomethingElse> { ... }` or, more generally, `class Base<TSelf, T0, T1, ...> where TSelf : Base<TSelf, T0, T1, ...>`

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using Generics. For example you can use something like that:

```
public class MainStatic<T> where T : MainStatic<T>
{
    public static void Foo()
    {
    }

    static MainStatic()
    {
        RuntimeHelpers.RunClassConstructor(typeof(T).TypeHandle);
    }
}

public class SubStatic : MainStatic<SubStatic>
{
    public static void Bar()
    {
    }
}

public class Instance
{
    public void FooBar()
    {
        SubStatic.Foo();
        SubStatic.Bar();
    }
}
```

Comment: When you call `Foo` on `SubStatic` the static constructor (cctor) on `SubStatic` is not called. This is one of the OP's questions, how to force the cctor to run when a static member from its base is called.

Comment: Indeed, my bad I didn't check this. I'll see if I can change this.

Comment: see my answer, you just need to call `RuntimeHelpers.RunClassConstructor(typeof (T).TypeHandle);`

Comment: @mlorbetske Yeah indeed, just updated my answer. Actually you already got it in the second part of your answer, not much value added in my answer.